# Api response not set in redux state for nested route in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am learning redux and reactjs. But I am stuck in set api response in redux state. I did nested route like below.

```
import { initApplication } from './actions/LoadInitialParameters';
store.dispatch(initApplication());
render(
<Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
        <div>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
                <Route exact path="/test" component={App}/>
                <Route  path="/register" component={Registration}/>
                <Route  path="/register/pet/more" component={Registration}/>
            </Switch>
        </div>
    </ConnectedRouter>
</Provider>,
document.getElementById('root'))
```

The problem is like when I go to register path the api response set in redux state but for /register/pet/more path api response not set in the redux state.

Give some solution for this issue

Thanks

Comment: How are you accessing (and writing to) the redux state? It should be the same for everyone, and does not depend on the route.

Comment: I'm using react-redux connect for accessing redux state

Comment: What is the difference between path="/register" and path=/register/pet/more", it would be great if you add more info on how you save the state in redux store and how are you retrieving it in components